# Video Streaming in Android

Tags: android, streaming, video-streaming, jmf

I have made an Application in Java that transmits video  (JMF= "JAVA MEDIA FRAMEWORK").
 Now I want an Android client for receiving video.  What steps do i follow to make such client.  I have seen that JMF doesnt work on Android.  I want to know best way of doing it in Android platform .

Answer (score 1):

Ah, yea.  JMF is effectively dead and useless.

Check out [the MediaPlayer class](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html) in Android.